# How to draw a circle in a numpy array with floating point radius at floating point position?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I've been searching on how to draw a circle in a Numpy array at floating point position with a floating point radius.

The [cv2.circle](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaf10604b069374903dbd0f0488cb43670) function expects integers:

```
cv.circle(img, center, radius, color[, thickness[, lineType[, shift]]]) ->  img
```

and this is limiting when precision is required.

Comment: the `shift` argument is the key. read the documentation carefully. if you pass `4` as shift, all the coordinates are considered to have four fractional bits, i.e. multiply all your float values by 2^4 = 16 and then round them to integers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Acutally, now that you say it, I remember having read about it, but it is so much more readable to use the `skimage` version…

Comment: I'd like the opencv drawing functions to take floats too (and accept numpy arrays beside tuples). the current APIs are highly inconvenient IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [skimage.draw](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.disk). It is possible to draw circles, disks, ellipsis and more, using floating point measures. Example here with drawing a disk.

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.draw

height, width = 50, 50
target = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)
x, y = 21.5, 18.2
radius = 14.3
target[skimage.draw.disk((x,y), radius=radius)] = 1
```

Installation with `pip install scikit-image`. Or look at their [installation documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/install.html).